# Command Line to Delete Files and Folders and Sub Folders in Directory, Except Those Who Were Created Today

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, windows-7

I want to write a batch file to cleanup my Downloads folder by deleting everything in it Except Files and Folders that were created today.
 Thanks.

Comment: On Linux (probably Mac too) it is very easy : `find path/to/downloads -mtime +1 -exec rm {} \;` You could always install Cygwin to execute this command.

Comment: What about using powershell? Is it acceptable? If yes, then: Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -lt ([DateTime]::Today)} | Remove-Item -WhatIf

Comment: sorry, I want to use command line.

Comment: You could get a better answer if you define exactly how you need to process folders. This may be part of why you are being downvoted / getting close votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using modern Windows, recommend you use [forfiles](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753551.aspx),

Folder can still messy. Do you want to do it based on the timestamp of the directory itself? Do you want to process recursively through all folders, deleting files based on date and then delete the folder if it empty after deleting the files of given age. There are other reasonable interpretations of your question as well. Personally, I use a python script so I can make the file cleanup do exactly what I want. This may also be why Uriil suggested PowerShell.

Arguably, Windows Services for Unix [downloadable from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=274) would be considered fair game (allowing the find command mentioned by Johnride). If you use this, make sure Johnride suggestion matches your actual intent. For the find command, using the option -print instead of -exec is great for debugging

If you can use forfiles, this [article may give what you want.](http://elderec.org/2012/02/scripting-delete-files-and-folders-older-than-x-days/) I taking the liberty of pasting in the batch file solution using forfiles from the article.

```
@echo off
:: set folder path
set dump_path=c:\shares\dump

:: set min age of files and folders to delete
set max_days=1

:: remove files from %dump_path%
forfiles -p %dump_path% -m *.* -d -%max_days% -c "cmd  /c del /q @path"

:: remove sub directories from %dump_path%
forfiles -p %dump_path% -d -%max_days% -c "cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE rd /S /Q @path"
```

Comment: This is great at deleting the older files, but does not delete any of the empty directories.